# WooCommerce product list filtering using multiple attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am novice to WordPress and WooCommerce.

I am using `Wordpress 4.9.8` and `WooCommerce plugin version 3.5.2`.

What I want to do is, list the products that have matching attributes I provided.

For that I have used a short-code as:

```
<?php
do_shortcode('[product_attribute attribute="material" filter="abc" attribute="diameter" filter="1.65 inch" paginate="true" limit="15"]');
?>
```

But however, it returns the list of products having material "Abc" **OR** having diameter "1.65 inch". What I want is list of products having material "Abc" **AND** diameter "1.65 inch".

Later on I need to pass two more attributes for products filtering and I want the product list with products having

```
material = "abc" AND diameter="somediameter" AND some_attribute = "XYZ" AND so on..
```

How can I get this? Any short codes?

Comment: Woocommerce shortcode can only handle just **one product attribute taxonomy** as you can have only one `attribute` argument *(and only one `filter` argument too)* in the shortcode. Also since woocommerce 3.2 `[product_attribute]` is [replaced by `[products]`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6)… So you should need to build your own short code…

Comment: OK thanks for the comment. And how can I build it? Any example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_shortcode_products_query

Answer (score 0):

##### Hello.

You can do this using **WP_QUERY** or what I will say next..

You can write a code similar to what I wrote below. Of course, it's not standard and it's not rational, but it's the only thing you can use with a shortcode

With ob_Start() and DOMXpath [in php] , you can get the html codes of two shortcodes and find the common between them with array_intersect. Although I say again, this is not a standard work and the most **correct way is to
Use WP_QUERY**

Thanks for the google translator

### References

[-> Convert DOMXpath Query to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321927/should-this-xpath-query-be-returning-an-array-or-a-single-value-in-php)

[-> WP_QUERY Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_shortcode_products_query)