# Should this XPath query be returning an array, or a single value in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I *think* I have an issue with XPath, where it's not behaving as I expect, although I could be expecting something wrong!

I would like to ask why the following line I'm using to set a PHP variable from an attribute value is returning an array, with several levels before I get to the value, rather than a string of the value.

The start of my XML file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReaderDetails updated="16/12/2020 10:33:02">
```

I want to get the value of 'updated' as a string, and set to a variable, which I believed I could do using this:

```
$updated = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xml), null, true)->xpath('//ReaderDetails/@updated');
```

However, when debugging in NetBeans, the result I get from the variable is a nested array, with the attribute name and value inside:

[image]

How can I fix my PHP variable line (particularly the Xpath) and why isn't this working as expected?

Extra notes:

1. There is only one `ReaderDetails` node

Comment: You get a nested array because, for all PHP knows, there may be multiple `ReaderDetails` nodes. It'll give you the attribute for each node found.

Comment: Okay, thanks for this. I know there's only one ReaderDetails node in the file, if this makes any difference?

Comment: Sure, but my point is that the API doesn't, so it returns an array always. It's won't change what it returns just for cases where it the XML structure is X as opposed to Y.

Comment: OKay I understand that, so I can remove the first array, but adding `[0]` to the end of the line, but it's the @attribute and value that I need to get that's more important.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` will always return an array of SimpleXMLElement instances. If your expression matches something not an element node it will still simulate one that can be cast to string for the value.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<ReaderDetails updated="16/12/2020 10:33:02"/>
XML;

$updated = simplexml_load_string($xml, null, true)->xpath('//ReaderDetails/@updated');
var_dump((string)$updated[0]);
var_dump($updated);
```

Output:

```
string(19) "16/12/2020 10:33:02"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["updated"]=>
      string(19) "16/12/2020 10:33:02"
    }
  }
}
```

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` is able to return scalar values directly - depending on the xpath expression:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<ReaderDetails updated="16/12/2020 10:33:02"/>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$nodeList = $xpath->evaluate('//ReaderDetails/@updated');
var_dump(get_class($nodeList));
var_dump(get_class($nodeList[0]));
$nodeContent = $xpath->evaluate('string(//ReaderDetails/@updated)');
var_dump($nodeContent);
```

Output:

```
string(11) "DOMNodeList"
string(7) "DOMAttr"
string(19) "16/12/2020 10:33:02"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to stumble across an answer that solved this, by setting teh variable as a string once it's set.

```
$updated = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xml), null, true)->xpath('//ReaderDetails/@updated')[0];
$updated = (string) $updated;
```

This now returns the variable as a string, containing the date and time value of the attribute.